# Bootstrap progress bars show empty when uploaded to server

Tags: php, html, progress-bar

Does anyone know why these progress bars are showing as empty when I upload my file? I've used them before a while ago and they worked okay, although now that I'm using data from a database, they don't work?

```
$count1 = 10;
$count2 = 14;
$count3 = 18;
$count4 = 22;

<div class="panel-body">
                       <div class="progress progress-striped">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" value="<? echo $count1; ?>">
    <span class="sr-only">40% Complete (success)</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="progress progress-striped">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" value="<? echo $count2; ?>">
    <span class="sr-only">20% Complete</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="progress progress-striped">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" value="<? echo $count3; ?>">
    <span class="sr-only">60% Complete (warning)</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="progress progress-striped">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" value="<? echo $count4; ?>">
    <span class="sr-only">80% Complete</span>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are missing the style width attribute in your `div`

Try to replace:

```
value="<? echo $count2; ?>">
```

with:

```
style="width: <? echo $count2; ?>%"
```

With what you are doing here the `value` will not work.

Comment: Do I need to change this in all of them or just for $count2 ?

Answer (score 0):

you have to set width attributes too :

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="<? echo $count1 ?>" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: <?= echo $count1 ?>%;">
    <span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>
  </div>
</div>
```